# Set up Android Studio 1.5 preview with native debugging

Tags: debugging, android-studio, gradle, java-native-interface

I want to debug an Android App which uses native C++ code via jni. When I edit the run-configurations to Android-Native I receive the error warning:

Build type isn't JNI debuggable.

Could someone tell me how to setup Android Studio 1.5 preview 2 for native debugging.
Or is it better to use another version?

regards Peter

Comment: no one? I just need a recommendation and perhaps a link to a sample project.

Comment: Did setting `jniDebuggable true` in `buildTypes` for release or debug mode in `build.gradle` fixes the issue for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to setup your android project to be built by experimental gradle buildtool which allows you to debug native code.

Please refer to this link: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental